# .net and .config files

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, configuration-files

I have the following stored in a stores.config file inside my asp.net website's root folder.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientId" value="127605460617602"/>
        <add key ="RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:49548/Redirect.aspx"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

How can I use `string Clientid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"].ToString();` to call it up from that file? Calling it as it of course does not work as it is looking for it in web.config.

I do not want to put the appSettings in the web.config file. Is that allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) your `stores.config` file from `web.config`

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="stores.config">
  </appSettings>
<configuration>
```

Your `stores.config` file should have the following structure:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="127605460617602"/>
    <add key ="RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:49548/Redirect.aspx"/>
</appSettings>
```

Alternatively you can also use:
 [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration Method (ExeConfigurationFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx)

For example:

```
// Map the new configuration file.
var configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "stores.config";


 // Get the mapped configuration file
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var clientid = config.AppSettings["ClientId"];
```

Comment: That's exactly waht I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Quick question, if I modify the stores.config file and saved it again, when I rebuild/test the page it does not refresh the content. How to force update it?

Comment: You will have to restart your web server.

Comment: Yes I knew about that, just wondering if there was a quicker way. Thanks